# Content-Length header on HHVM FastCGI is intermittent

Tags: php, hhvm

Maybe it's the jetlag, but I'm failing to make PHP/HHVM give me the *Content-Type* header when I need it.

I've deployed the full stack (MySQL, HHVM, Nginx) on a Vagrant machine and I've managed to reproduce the issue on a test script:

```
<?php
$file='/usr/share/doc/iptables/html/NAT-HOWTO.html'; # random test file
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
echo(readfile($file));
?>
```

If you examine the headers with curl:

```
hostname:~ jsimpson$ curl -I http://vagrant/test.php
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Tue, 16 Sep 2014 22:09:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2592
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: HHVM/3.2.0
Content-Encoding: none;
```

We have a content length header.  However if we hit the same URL from Chrome, and get the headers from the Dev tools:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Tue, 16 Sep 2014 22:14:41 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: HHVM/3.2.0
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

No Content-Length header.  I've also packet sniffed this to verify that the header isn't sent.  I can switch to PHP FPM and it sends the header.

Comment: Notice that the `Content-Encoding` is different – my guess is that the `Content-Length` works fine for uncompressed resources, but when gzip compression comes into play the value you output in your script gets removed because it does not match the actual length of the _compressed_ data.

Comment: That's a very good observation and hypothesis.  Thanks, I'll investigate.

Comment: `Content-length` isn't set for `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced the issue by hitting the server with:

```
curl -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' --compressed -v http://foo/bar
```

HHVM enables compression by default.  Disabling that gave me the header back.

Everything was awesome after adding this to **/etc/hhvm/server.ini**

```
hhvm.server.gzip_compression_level = 0
```

Comment: Thank you, this disabled GZIP compression as well. Was looking at NGINX server configuration all the time, turns out it's HHVM compressing output.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this issue/feature. Not running HHVM though. Pure nginx + PHP-FPM. 
The thing is, if your PHP app calculates and sets Content-Lenght header field, and your nginx is configured to gzip content, it will just ditch this information and replace it by Chunked transfer encoding and GZIP headers. 
So do not set GZIP to a very small buffers, default is 20 bytes which does quite the opposite (end result is larger then before GZIP compression).
I set it like this:
`gzip_min_length 1024;`